# Drupal 7 | Automatd Unit Testing

Tags: unit-testing, drupal, drupal-7, phpunit, simpletest

I need to write some automated unit testing for my site built in Drupal 7. I am sniffing through PHPUnit and SimpleTest for this work.

However, I could not figure it out which one to use with D7. So, keeping D7 in mind, which of these suites more for the job?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use Selenium IDE,It is a open source tool for automated testing,there You can record and playback the scripts.
You can export the test case in the any language you are familar ex- java,python etc.
There export test case used in the Selenium webdriver.
Selenium Ide, webdriver used for the web application.